# Integrate real function returns complex function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, special-functions, integral-equations

I want to compute the integral
$$
\int_0^c \exp(-cx+x^2) \mathrm{d}x,
$$
where $c>0$ is an unknown constant. In *Mathematica* Version 12.2.0

```
$Version

(* 12.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 12, 2020) *)
```

I evaluate the integral and I obtain

```
Integrate[Exp[-c*x + x^2], {x, 0, c}, Assumptions -> {c > 0}]

(* E^(-(c^2/4)) Sqrt[\[Pi]] Erfi[c/2] *)
```

Why do I obtain a complex expression? Is it a bug or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)" *)

int[c_] = Integrate[Exp[-c*x + x^2], {x, 0, c}]

(* E^(-(c^2/4)) Sqrt[π] Erfi[c/2] *)
```

[`Erfi`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Erfi.html) is real for real `c`

```
FunctionDomain[int[c], c]

(* True *)

Plot[int[c], {c, -15, 15}]
```

[image]

For an alternate representation using [`DawsonF`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DawsonF.html) (**EDIT:** Eliminated unnecessary assumption)

```
int[c] // FullSimplify

(* 2 DawsonF[c/2] *)
```